# Tealium Journey Builder conector

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

We are trying to install Tealium Journey Builder conector, but when asked for Marketing Cloud API credentials we are getting an error:
[image]

We have no detail on what type of Installed Packages has to be created, we are trying with "web app" and "server to server"

Has anyone had this problem too?

Comment: I’m going to guess that tealium is only setup to use the legacy app since they are not asking for a TSE. You may want to reach out to them to see if this is true and they need to improve their connection

Comment: Server to server is the way to go - can you see if you are able to authenticate using Postman?

Comment: Tried out server to server unsuccessfully (OAuth2.0), tried out a legacy integration too, same result.
We've authenticated without trouble using postman.

Comment: You should get somebody from Tealium on the line who can read the complete error logs. I have done that in the past for a responsys integration with tealium. After a quick call of 15 to 30min everything was set up correctly. My guess would have been that it should work with legacy packages. But since you tried that already..
And like mentioned before: Server to Server is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the info, issue was ip whitelisting related. We had to whitelist Tealium IPs on Marketing Cloud, and now it's working.